# Bootstrap4 validation not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, internet-explorer-11

it works perfectly in chrome and edge, but not in IE11. I have tried to remove novalidate, but it makes the validation only work in IE11.

this is my code :

```
<form class="m-t needs-validation" id="needs-validation" role="form" action="index.html" novalidate>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
               Please enter a valid username.
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
               Please enter a valid password.
          </div>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Login</button>
</form>
```

And event listener in javascript like this:

```
<script>
        (function() {
          'use strict';
          window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
            var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
                form.addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {
                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  event.stopPropagation();
                }
                form.classList.add('was-validated');
              }, false);
            });
          }, false);
        })();
</script>
```

Do I am doing wrong in my code and how to fix it, so it would work in IE11 too?

Comment: There is no issue with your code. It's working on any browser finely.. (`novalidate` with or without even).

Comment: I found the way to fix it, it was my mistake, I didn't allow blocked content (IE restricted from running script)

Comment: yeah you should allow blocked content.. yes that restricted scripts. Try to focus on console log always.

Comment: From your last comment, it seems that you have solved the issue. I suggest that you can post the solution as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to fix it, just simply allow blocked content alert in IE11 (at the bottom) that say that IE11 restricted script and ActiveX control.